# Solutions affine combination sine cosine equal frequency

Tags: trigonometry

In my research of inverse kinematics, one of the challenges is to find the solutions ($\theta$) to the following equation:

$a \sin(\theta) + b \cos(\theta) = c$

Where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are known constants. So the question is:

- When does this equation have a solution?
- What is that solution

Comment: Start by combining the two terms on the left into a single sinusoidal term. There are many explanations of how to do this fairly standard transformation on the web.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/535600/265466 for how to perform this transformation.