# How to get the maximum value of the sum in two sides in two right triangles?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, maxima-minima

The problem is as follows:

> The figure from below shows two triangles intersected on point $E$. Assume $AE=3\,m$ and $ED=1\,m$. Find the maximum value of $AB+EC$

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The given choices in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\sqrt{10}\,m\\
2.&\4\,m\\
3.&\sqrt{5}\,m\\
4.&\4\,m\\
\end{array}$

The official solution for this problem according to my book is shown below:

Let $M=AB+EC$

Notice on the figure:

[image: Sketch of the solution]

$AB=3\sin x$

and $EC=\cos x$

$M=3\sin x+\cos x$

$M=\sqrt{10}\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}\sin x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\cos x\right)$

$\tan \alpha =\frac{1}{3}$

$M=\sqrt{10}\left(\sin (x+\alpha)\right)$

Also notice that $x$ and $\alpha$ are acute angles.

Therefore:

$0<x+\alpha<\pi$

$\sin (x+\alpha)\leq 1$

Thus the maximum $M$ is $\sqrt{10}$.

*There is where it ends the official solution.*

But I am confused, **where exactly is that alpha** that is being talking about?, **how did the author came up with the idea of $\sqrt{10}$ and the use of $\frac{1}{3}$.**

Could someone **please explain me, the logic that the author used** and **offer an alternate solution**, perhaps easier to understand and less to guess what it was meant?.

I appreciate a **step by step solution** so I can understand.

Comment: This may help with the motivation: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1037871/97045

Answer (score 2):

Any expression in the form $a\sin x+b\cos x$ can be written as $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin x+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos x\right)$. Note that $\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)^2=1$ which means that we can interpret these two expressions as cosine and sine of some angle $\alpha$. Think of a right triangle with legs $3$ and $1$ and you will understand what $\alpha$ is.

Comment: The sum-of-squares expression shows $M$ is *at most* $\sqrt{10}$. The point of calculating $\alpha$ is to work out if $\sqrt{10}$ is actually achievable or whether it would violate other constraints on $x$, such as it being an acute angle. If $\sqrt{10}$ turned out to be impossible, the answer would be whatever the maximum is at the $x$ where  the other constraints bind.

Comment: @ThomasLumley So alpha isn't something we can put in the figure, it appears as a consequence of the sum of angles identity?. The second part regarding if it would be impossible to achieve $\sqrt{10}$ I do understand, but in this problem there aren't any. I just wonder, **why** did the author bothered to state this interval? $0<x+\alpha<\pi$ I mean cosine or sine functions will be maximum at 1 in all its domain isn't it?. By the way I like your avatar.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, the way I learned this is a little different from how your textbook seems to have done it - I was taught to incorporate the cosine function while they are using the *sine* function.

The first steps of the solution are simple enough. Since we are scaling $AE$ and $ED$ by $m$, every segment will have a factor of $m$ in it. For this reason, when we take $\sin{x}=\frac{AB}{3m}$ and multiply both sides by $3m$, we get $3m\sin{x}=AB'm$, where $AB'=\frac{AB}{m}$. Simplifying on both sides, we get $3\sin{x}=AB'$. The logic is similar for finding $\cos{x}=EC'$ .

Now we begin to investigate $M=AB+EC=\cos{x}+3\sin{x}$. Consider the point $(1,3)$, with the 1 coming from the coefficient of our cosine function, and the 3 from the coefficient of our sine function. This point can be rewritten in polar form. If you have not learned this yet, the polar form of a point describes its notation not in terms of distance from the x and y-axes, but in terms of its distance from the origin and the angle between the line connecting the point to the origin and the x-axis. So, for our point $(1,3)$, it is a trivial matter to calculate its distance from the origin. It is simply $\sqrt{10}$. As for the angle, which we will call $\alpha$, we can calculate it by remembering the definition of the tangent function and saying $\tan{\alpha}=3$, or $\alpha=\arctan{3}$.

Here is the clever part. By definition, $\cos{\alpha}\sqrt{10}=1$ and $\sin{\alpha}\sqrt{10}=3$, and thus $\cos{\alpha}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$ and $\sin{\alpha}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}$. We can rewrite our function $M$ as $M=\sqrt{10}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\cos{x}+\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}\sin{x})$. This is the exact same as $M=\sqrt{10}(\cos{\alpha}\cos{x}+\sin{\alpha}\sin{x})$. This should look incredibly familiar, because after applying the difference of angle theorem for cosine, what we have now is $M=\sqrt{10}(\cos{(x-\alpha)})$.

Now, here's the kicker. What $\alpha$ is actually equal to does not matter particularly much in this problem, since we are trying to maximize $M$. We know that for any argument, the maximum value of $\cos{x}$ is 1. And thus, the maximum value of $\sqrt{10}(\cos{x})$ is $\sqrt{10}$. After factoring our $m$ that we took out earlier back in, we see that the maximum value of $AB+EC=\sqrt{10}m$.

Comment: Please note that $m$ is not an unknown. It is the notation for meters. But I appreciate that the first paragraph does explain the logic of trignometrical correspondence with the unknown lenghts. I do understand the explanation about where does alpha comes from, but it seems to be like an auxiliary angle which is not part of the initial figure itself but rather as a consequence of the sum of angles indentity which explains the cosine or sine function is shifted.

Comment: However is my assumption regarding alpha correct?. Because I was trying to spot this in the figure. Moreover, the author uses this inequality $0<x+\alpha<\pi$ but **is this important?** then it says that alpha and $x$ are both acute in order to arrive the mentioned inequality. I found $\tan{-1}3\approx 71.57^\circ$ which does makes sense adding two accute angles will not exceed $\pi$, which I believe was the logic used here.

Comment: But taking the function individually term by term in this inequality will not be wise as I could end up with $0<\cos(x+\alpha)<0$, instead I have to use what the definition of cosine is. But if this is held true for all the domain why to bother to state that inequality on the first place?. I find this confusing maybe you could help me to answer this part please. By the way, sorry for the late reply I had to take time to understand your answer.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Let $AM=CD$ and $AN=DE$

Since $\angle AMN=\angle CDE$,(cyclic quadrilateral),  $\triangle AMN \cong \triangle DCE$, then, $AN=ED=1$

Let $AB=x$, and, $EC=MN=y$

Since $\triangle ABE \sim \triangle AMN$, (AAA Similarity), $BE=3y$

FIRST ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION:

$x^2+9y^2=9$, in $\triangle ABE$

$x=\sqrt{9-9y^2}$

To find max$(x+y)$

$f(y)=\sqrt{9-9y^2}+y$

$f'(y)=\frac{-9y}{\sqrt{9-9y^2}}+1=0$

There is a maximum when $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$ ,and, $x=\frac{9}{\sqrt{10}}$

$\text{max}(AB+EC)=\text{max}(x+y)=\frac{10}{\sqrt{10}}=\sqrt{10}$

SECOND ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION:

$x^2+9y^2=9$, in $\triangle ABE$

To find max$(x+y)$

Applying Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

$$(x+y)^2=(x+\frac{1}{3}\times 3y)^2\leq (1^2+(\frac{1}{3})^2)\times (x^2+(3y)^2)=$$
$$=(1+\frac{1}{9})\times (x^2+9y^2)=$$
$$=(1+\frac{1}{9})\times 9=10$$

$$x+y\leq\sqrt{10}$$

Comment: @Vasya I don't know how to use the Caushy Swartz inequality. Can you teach me how did you use it here?. The [wikipedia entry on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) uses vectors and I don't know how does this applies here. Sorry I am a beginner. Please explain why $\left(x+\frac{1}{3}\times 3y\right)^2\leq \left(1^2+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2\right)\leq \left(x^2+(3y)^2\right)$ why does this becomes into $\left(1+\frac{1}{9}\times(x^2+9y^2\right)$?. Please explain this I'm stuck.

Comment: $(ax+by)^2\leq (a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)$